# Second Order Nonhomogeneous Differential Equation (Method of Undetermined Coefficients)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution of the following Differential equation
$y''-2y'+10y=e^xcos(3x)$
We know that the general solution for 2nd order Nonhomogeneous differential equations is the sum of $y_p+y_c$ where $y_c$ is the general solution of the homogeneous equation and $y_p$ the solution of the nonhomogeneous.
Therefore $y_c=e^x(c_1cos(3x)+c_2cos(3x))$
Now we have to find $y_p$. I know in fact that $y_p=e^xxsin(3x)/6$  but i do not know how to get there.

Comment: You get there by using the method of undetermined coefficients. Did you try to apply that method? What did you get?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes i tried. I know that y must be a polyonomial of the same degree as $e^xcos(3x)$ and also by using the following information. $y_p=Ax^2+Bx+C$ , $y_p'=2Ax+B$ and $y_p''=2A$ but i end up with a different result

Answer (score 1):

since the RHS is a soln of the homogeneous eqn, we can try x multiplied by it. let $y_p$ be a linear combination of $xe^x\cos(3x)$ and $xe^x\sin(3x)$.
$y_p=axe^x\cos(3x)+bxe^x\sin(3x)$
Let $E=D^2-2D+10$ , where $D$ is the derivative operator.
$E[y_p]=-6ae^x\sin(3x)+6be^x\cos(3x)$
$E[y_p]=e^x\cos(3x)$
equating coeffs,
$a=0$ and $6b=1$
$y_p=\frac{1}{6}xe^x\sin(3x)$

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So the equation $E=D^2-2D+10$ is the auxiliary equation right?Also why a=0?

Comment: @PaulK. not quite. but if you equate the RHS to zero, then it is. a=0 bcos 2nd expression didnt have e^xsin(3x) term.

Comment: but why did we use this equation in the first place? Correct me if i am wrong but if we plug $D=e^xcos(3x)$ then $D^2-2D+10=-10e^xcos(3x)+10$. Also why do we have to multiply x with our first solution .

Comment: I think that the problem would be simpler to look at starting with $y=z \,e^x$. This would give
$z''+9z=\cos(3x)$. Now what are the roots of the characteristic equation ?

Comment: so if we use $y=ze^x$ then $y'=z'e^x+ze^x$  and $y''=z''e^x+z'e^x+ze^x+z'e^x$ Therefore $z''+9z=cos(3x)$ And the homogeneous differential equation has a general solution that looks like this $z=c_1cos(3x)+c_2sin(3x)$ How can i find the general solution for the nonhomogeneous . that's the difficulty i am facing

Comment: @PaulK. you can't sub D=e^xcos(3x) bcos D is not a function of x. D is a derivative operator. as for why we multiply by x, bcos we when we sub e^xcos(3x) into y, the LHS gives 0. so we try another function.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error i finnaly understand the strategy behind this type of differential equation. So here's is what i did in order to find the solution (I will provide as much information as i can)
In order to calculate a nonhomogeneous differntial equation we must first find the general solution of the homogeneous. So
$y''-2y'+10y=o$ (1) using the Auxiliary equation we can easily find that the general solution is $y_h=e^x(C_1cos(3x)+C_2sin(3x)$
Now as cineel mentioned above we can try $y_h$ multiplied by x
Thus $y_p=Axe^xcos(3x)+Bxe^xsin(3x)$
Now we have to differentiate $y_p$ two times
So $y_p=Axe^xcos(3x)+Bxe^xsin(3x)$ (1)
$y_p'=A[e^xcos(3x)+xe^xcos(3x)-xe^x3sin(3x)]+B[e^xsin(3x)+xe^xsin(3x)+3xe^xcos(3x)$ (2)
$y_p''=A[-8xe^xcos(3x)-6e^xxsin(3x)+2e^xcos(3x)-3e^xsin(3x)]+B[-8xe^xsin(3x)+6e^xxcos(3x)+2e^xsin(3x)+6e^xcos(3x)]$ (3)

Therefore substituting (1)(2)(3) in our original differential equation we end up with $-3Ae^xsin(3x)+6Be^xcos(3x)=e^xcos(3x)$

So A=0 and B=1/6

Thus (1) Now becomes $y_p=1/6xe^xsin(3x)$

So $y_p+y_h=e^x[C_1cos(3x)+C_2sin(3x)]+1/6e^xxsin(3x)$